# Computing the Probability of travelling in the rain without an umbrella

Tags: probability, markov-process

An Individual possesses a total of $n$ umbrellas that she uses in going from her home to her office, and vice versa.

If she is at home (at the office) at the beginning (end) of a day  and it is raining, then she will take an umbrella when travelling to the office (to home) provided there is one to be taken.

If it is not raining, then she never takes an umbrella.

Assuming  that, independent of  the past, it rains at the beginning (end) of each a day with probability $p$, during what fractions of trips is she travelling in the rain without an umbrella?

***$\underline{Solution}$***:

Let's break this down:

- The individual has ***n*** umbrellas total
- If it is raining when leaving home, she will take an umbrella to the office if there is one available
- If it is raining when leaving the office, she will take an umbrella home if there is one available
- She travels home to office and office to home each day
- It rains at the start of a day with probability ***p***, independent of the past
- It rains at the end of a day with probability ***p***, independent of the past

Let's look at the probability she travels in the rain without an umbrella:

Going from home to office:

- It rains with probability ***p***
- If it rains, she takes an umbrella if one is available
- The probability there are no umbrellas left is the probability it rained in the last n trips from the office to home.
- By independence, this is $(1-p)^n$

So the probability she travels from home to office in the rain without an umbrella is $p(1-p)^n$

Going from office to home:

- Same logic - the probability is $p(1-p)^n$

Since she makes these trips every day, the fraction of trips where she travels in the rain without an umbrella is:

$2p(1-p)^n$

So the final answer is $2p(1-p)^n$

In my opinion, this solution is correct. Any doubt?

Comment: The correct number of umbrellas to own is either 3 or 41.

Comment: Re "The probability there are no umbrellas left is the probability it rained in the last n trips from the office to home."  Why should that be?  Maybe it rained only in the morning for the first $n+1$ trips and has been dry ever since.  Consider working through a few examples with tiny $n,$ such as $n=1$ and $n=2.$

Comment: @whuber, $(1-p)^n$ is the probability of no rains in the last $n$ trips from office to home. Hence, the probability that " there are no umbrellas left at home  when an Individual starts trip from home to office" is $p(1-p)^n$.

Comment: You have tagged the question with `markov-process`, and rightfully so, I think. After some time, one would assume that the Markov chain describing the number of umbrellas when leaving home, say, has reached stationarity, and the probability in question is meant as the probability of no umbrellas, and rain - is that correctly understood?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the probability that the question does not refer to the very first days after the observations started, but rather to the "long run".

#### Use a Markov chain model

$\newcommand{\bpi}{\boldsymbol\pi}$
Since we assume that the weather of today does not depend on yesterday, and even morning and evening are independent, you can model the number of umbrellas at home (or at work) by a [**Markov chain**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Let $X_t$ be the number of umbrellas at home on the morning of day $t$.
It is a random variable that only can take values $0,1,\dots,n$.

As for all Markov chains, the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ is specified by the **transition probabilities**,
$$
p_{ij} = P(X_{t+1}=j\mid X_t = i),\quad i, j \in\{0,\dots,n\}.
$$
These transition probabilities do not depend on the current time $t$. However,  distribution of $X_t$ will depend on the start value $x_1$, the initial number of umbrellas at home, through all the intermediate steps:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  P(X_t=k) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n} p_{jk}P(X_{t-1}=j)
  \\&=\sum_{j=0}^{n} p_{jk}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} p_{ij}P(X_{t-2}=i)\right) \\&=\dots
 \end{aligned} 
$$

##### On the long run, the Markov chain approaches a stationary distribution

When days go by, with increasing $t$,
the distribution of the $X_t$ becomes less and less dependent on $x_1$, and converges to the distribution of a random variable $X$ , $X_t \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{\text{D}} X$.
We denote by $\bpi_k$ the probability that on the long run, there are $k$ umbrellas at home in the morning, $\bpi_k=P(X=k)$. The distribution $\bpi$ is called **stationary** distribution of the chain.

When the Markov chain has (approximately) reached equilibrium, we can assume that $P(X_{t+1}=k) = P(X_{t}=k) = \bpi_k$. Then

$$
\begin{equation} 
\bpi_k = P(X_{t+1}=k) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} p_{jk}\bpi_j,\quad k=0,\dots, n.
\end{equation}
$$

For the umbrellas, the most of the elements in the sum vanish, because the number of umbrellas at home can only change by $\pm 1$ during one day.

<sub>Note that not all Markov chains automatically have a stationary distribution. Some condtions have to be fulfilled, but we are on the safe side with the umbrella chain.</sub>

###### How can we use all this to find the probability to get wet?

The only quantity we need to find is the probability to have to leave the home without an umbrella, that is, there is no umbrella in the house. This is the same idea as you suggested in your question. On the long run, the probability of having no umbrella in the morning of an average day is
$$
   P(X = 0) = \pi_0.
$$

To find this probability, we need to solve the system of equations given by (1). But before we can solve it, we have to specify the transition probabilities $p_{jk}$.

#### Transition probabilities for the umbrellas, and stationary distribution

We have only three possible transitions, depending on the weather at day $n$:

a) no change, $X_t=k \to X_{t+1}=k$.

- For $0<k<n$, this is possible on days where there either is no rain, or when it rains both in the morning and in the evening. The probability for this change is
  $$p_{kk} = (1-p)^2 + p^2 = 1 - 2p(1-p).$$
- For $k=0$, this is possible when it does not rain in the evening, thus
  $$p_{00} = (1-p).$$
- For $k=n$, all umbrellas are at home. There will be no change in umbrella number unless it rains in the morning, but not in the evening:
  $$p_{n\,n} = 1-p(1-p).$$

b) increase by 1, $X_t=k \to X_{t+1}=k+1$.
This requires to leave the home without umbrella, and to return with one that had been at the office because of evening rain. It is not possible when already all umbrellas are at home.

- if $k = 0$, it only needs to rain in the evening:
  $$ p_{0\,1} = p.$$
- for $0<k<n$,
  $$p_{k\, k+1}=(1-p)\cdot p.$$

c) decrease by 1, $X_t=k \to X_{t+1}=k-1$.
This occurs when it rains in the morning, but not in the evening, and requires at least one umbrella at home. Thus, for $k>0$,
$$p_{k\, k-1}=p\cdot(1-p).$$

All other transitions never occur, and from (1), we have
$$
\bpi_k = p_{k-1\,k} \bpi_{k-1} +  p_{k\,k} \bpi_{k} +  p_{k-1\,k} \bpi_{k+1}
$$
<sup>(as far as the individual transition probabilities are defined for $k$)</sup>

More precisely, with the abbreviation $a=p(1-p)$, the stationary distribution of the chain fulfils
$$  
\begin{align}
  (2)&&\bpi_{0} &= (1-p)\bpi_{0} + a\bpi_{1},\\
  (3)&&\bpi_{1} &= p\bpi_{0} + (1-2a)\bpi_{1}+ a\bpi_{2},
  \\&&&\vdots\notag\\
  (4)&&\bpi_{k} &= a\bpi_{k-1} + (1-2a)\bpi_{k}+ a\bpi_{k+1}, \qquad k=2,3,..,n-1
  \\&&&\vdots\notag\\
  (5)&&\bpi_{n} &= a\bpi_{n-1} + (1-a)\bpi_{n},
 \end{align} 
$$

Now we have $n+1$ equations that can be solved for $\bpi_0,\dots\bpi_{n}$.

From equation (2) we find $\bpi_0 = (1-p)\bpi_1$.
Plugging this in to (3), we get $\bpi_1=\bpi_2$.
Then from (4), with $k=2$, we get $\bpi_3=\bpi_2$.
Now we have $\bpi_1=\bpi_2=\bpi_3$, which in (3) recursively gives $\bpi_1=\dots=\bpi_{n-1}$.
Finally, (5) gives us $\bpi_{n}=\bpi_{n-1}$.

Taking into account that the probabilities $\bpi_0\dots\bpi_{n}$ have to sum to 1, w find
$$
\bpi_0=\frac{1-p}{n+1-p},\quad\bpi_k =\frac{1}{n+1-p}=\frac{1}{1-p}\bpi_0, \ \ k>0.
$$

This is an (imho) quite counterintuitive result - I would have expected that all possible numbers of umbrellas are equally likely, or perhaps, that numbers around $n$ are more likely than having no umbrellas at either home or office.

The event that the individual gets wet in the morning has thus probability
$p\bpi_0$. By symmetry, the same probability applies for getting wet in the evening. The overall result is
$$
P(\text{wet}) = \frac{2 p(1-p)}{n + 1 - p}.
$$

As one would hope, this probability decreases with $n$.

---

#### Checking by simulation

The following R code simulates the chain and estimate the fraction of wet trips:

```
simwet <- function(n=3, p=0.1, days=10000, nstart = n){
  # start with nstart at home
  n_home <- nstart
  n_office <- n - nstart
  # counting wet events
  wet <- 0  
  # now look at the development of umbrella stock at home (the slow way)
  for (i in 1:days){
    # make rain by runif(1)<p
    if (runif(1) < p){
      if (n_home == 0) wet  <- wet + 1
      else {
        n_home <- n_home - 1
        n_office <- n_office + 1
      }
    }
    if (runif(1) < p){
      if (n_office == 0) wet <- wet + 1
      else {
        n_office <- n_office - 1
        n_home <- n_home + 1
      }
    }
  }
  # fraction of wet trips
  wet / days
}

# theoretical result:
p_wet <- function(n, p) 2*p*(1-p)/(n+1-p)

# now run with n = 3, p = 0.2

set.seed(43)
replicate(5, simwet(3, 0.2))
# [1] 0.0849 0.0867 0.0809 0.0906 0.0799

p_wet(3, 0.2)
# [1] 0.08421053
```

Comment: The total number of umbrellas is $n.$ How, then, do the states come to be numbered $0$ through $2n$ and what do they mean?  According to the problem description, there are $2n+2$ (not $2n+1$) states.  They can be represented as ordered pairs $(k,a)$ where $k$ counts (say) the number of umbrellas at home and $a\in\{\text{home},\text{work}\}$ indicates the current location of our heroine.

Comment: @whuber, $0$ is when the heroine has run out of umbrellas at home, and is in risk of getting wet. Therefore $2n+1$ states. I'll add some simulation code (slow, but hopefully transparent).

Comment: I'm afraid it's not at all evident.  Please describe what your states mean.  That will help clarify how you are interpreting the question.

Comment: It is in the top of the Markov section, @whuber, but I am rewriting anyway to get rid of redundant complexity, and will then make the definition of $X_n$ stand out as equation

Comment: I read that and pointed out that it contradicts the question, where only $n,$ not $2n,$ umbrellas are available.  Moreover, I do not see how you can correctly model the chain solely by counting umbrellas: you also need to keep track of where the individual is.  Maybe it will turn out that can be avoided (for instance, by considering two transitions at once), but I don't see any analysis to that effect.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the $2n$ - it was a kind of typo when writing up and is of course confusing. I circumvented tracking the individual by looking at days as a whole. I'll add a simulation later.

Comment: I see that's it's simpler than I thought, because it doesn't matter whether transitions from $k$ umbrellas to $k$ umbrellas during the day occur because of two rainstorms or no rainstorms.  That's the key simplification.  (+1)

Comment: I meant "thanks for spotting nonsense in the first edits", @whuber :-)

Comment: the final P(wet) line clearly cannot be correct.   Imagine I own no umbrellas, and it rains with probability 0.9 with each journey...

P(wet) then calculates to 180%, which is clearly impossible...

Comment: Well spotted, you are right, @oliver-mattos, I calculated the average number of wet trips per day, not a probability of getting wet (from the question: "during what fractions of trips is she travelling in the rain without an umbrella"). And since there are two trips per day, the number has to be divided by two.